# User Object returns empty when trying to set class properties in constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

```
public $tracksSystemDir;
public $contentSystemDir;


public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    // setup system directory paths
    $this->tracksSystemDir = public_path() . '/users/' . $this->reference . '/tracks/';
    $this->contentSystemDir = public_path() . '/users/' . $this->reference . '/content/';
}
```

when i try to user $this->tracksSystemDir it returns empty, in fact User object returns empty

```
User {#420 ▼
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  +tracksSystemDir: "/home/vagrant/Code/9mmradio/public/storage/users//tracks/"
  +contentSystemDir: "/home/vagrant/Code/9mmradio/public/storage/users//content/"
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #forceDeleting: false
 }
```

This is returned user object when i dump the variable.
i have googled about this and i found nothing and i went through the documentation couple of time and found nothing regarding too.
So any help with this one is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you just want to add two properties to the user model??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add two properties to your user model, you can use `Accessors` as below:

```
public function getTracksSystemDirAttribute()
{
    return public_path() . '/users/' . $this->reference . '/tracks/';
}
```

then you can use it by saying:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->tracks_system_dir;
```

And the same can be done for any other property.

Note that the you should follow the naming as in the example. More on that in laravel documentation : [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: i have done it multiple times in the same project, bad memory :D.
anyway thanks for reminding it :)